# GET request with data-urlencode in PHP

Tags: php, curl, get, urlencode

I am trying to make an API call to Influx db from PHP program. The curl request to be made is -

```
curl -G 'http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true' --data-urlencode "q=SHOW MEASUREMENTS"
```

The code in PHP that I am stuck with is -

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true",
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
));
```

I am not sure in which **curl_setopt_array** should I send the **q=SHOW MEASUREMENTS**

Comment: Have you tried in url as
http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true&q=SHOW MEASUREMENTS 
?

Comment: If don't work, and you're passing a post, try 
CURLOPT_POST=> 1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => $_POST

Comment: had to do an urlencode and add the query string to the url... it works now! Thanks for pointing in the right direction  :)

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi That won't work since it's not yet url encoded. Spaces in the URL is encoded with `+`. So, that would be like `http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true&q=SHOW+MEASUREMENTS`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$query = urlencode("SHOW MEASUREMENTS");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true&q=" . $query,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : This is wrong! You should escape spaces in url string.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$q =  curl_escape($curl ,'SHOW MEASUREMENTS With spaces');
$url = "http://localhost:8086/query?pretty=true&q={$q}";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_URL => $url ,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false, // If You have https://
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
   CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
if( !$resp ){
   // log this Curl ERROR: 
   echo curl_error($curl) ;
}

curl_close($curl);
```